# gitting from branch to production

Tags: git, merge

I have a production server from some hosting company, so I can't put a git repository there.

I want to check the differences between my latest version in code to the prod server sources(its a php site).

I think that someone changed stuff at prod without update it in git. how can I check this stuff?
And maybe merge the changes or something ?

Any guides suggestions ?

My version control is git, the site is a cakephp based site.

Comment: So you want compare local version (with git repository) and version on remote host, isn't it?  What kind of access do you have/use for examining files on remote repository?

Comment: if you don't have git on the production server, how do you deploy your code to production? If you have ANY sort of command line access, you can run ls -lRc in your webroot directory and get a complete listing of the files with a datestamp of when they were last changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have clean repository (i.e. commit all your changes so that you don't lose them) and copy the code from the server to your local repository. You can then inspect the changes (using `git diff` or `gitk`) and commit them (or not).

Answer (score 0):

you can switch to your branch and type in your shell

```
git status
```

or

```
git log
```

That should show your untracked files if they havent been added and/or committed.

```
gitk
```

You can use gitK to show a graphical representation of your changes and branches

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative: copy all your remote file on your local machine, but *outside* your current working tree.

Type a:

```
 git --work-tree=/path/to/ftp/copy --git-dir=/path/to/your/local/git/repo/.git status
```

That way you can detect what has changed without erasing anything on your initial working tree.
That being said, if you want to commit, having a clean state in your current working directory (as [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006388/6309%29), committing or stashing first is advisable.